# Missing instance of MonadReader

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints, type-families

The code available from [github](https://github.com/jakubdaniel/test):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies
           , TypeOperators #-}

module Test where

import Control.Monad.Reader

import Control.Lens
import Control.Zipper

class Monad f => Family f where
    type Set f

-- This does not work
f :: Family f => (Top :>> [Set f] :>> Set f) -> f (Set f)
f = return . view focus

-- This here works
g :: Top :>> [Int] :>> Int -> Int
g = view focus
```

compiles fine with `ghc-8` but fails to compile with `ghc-7.10` with the error

```
Test.hs:16:14:
Could not deduce (MonadReader
                    (Zipper (Top :>> [Set f]) Int (Set f))
                    ((->) ((Top :>> [Set f]) :>> Set f)))
  arising from a use of `view'
from the context (Family f)
  bound by the type signature for
             f :: Family f => (Top :>> [Set f]) :>> Set f -> f (Set f)
  at Test.hs:15:6-57
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `view focus'
In the expression: return . view focus
In an equation for `f': f = return . view focus
```

in both cases exactly the same dependencies are used (`mtl 2.2.1`, `transformers 0.5.2`, `lens 4.14`, `zippers 0.2`) except `base` which can only be `4.8` for `ghc-7.10` and `4.9` for `ghc-8`. I really cannot figure out why it should compile with one compiler and not the other. I would like to make the code work for `ghc-7.10` as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: `:t frames (undefined :: Conf m) & view focus` is correctly resolved to `Set m` in ghci.

Comment: I have simplified the problem and moved the example to https://github.com/jakubdaniel/test .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know why this problem arises. But with the kind help of a user `puregreen` over on `#haskell` irc channel I was able to overcome this problem in this setting by simply replacing `view focus` with `(^. focus)`.